# In i2c_driver probe function get client->dev.id == 0

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, i2c

I'm writing i2c driver.
When my driver is probing client->dev.id is 0.
How can be 0?

//I need request shared interrupt, but I cannot if dev.id is 0.

Thank for explanation.

EDIT:
My DTS:

```
&i2c1{
my_dev1@21 {
    compatible = "test,bt125_exp";
    gpio-controller;
    #gpio-cells = <0x2>;
    interrupt-parent = <&gpio1>;
    interrupts = <0x4 0x02>;
    reg = <0x21 0x01>;
};

my_dev2@3a {
    compatible = "test,bt125";
    #gpio-cells = <0x2>;
    interrupt-parent = <&gpio1>;
    interrupts = <0x4 0x02>;
    reg = <0x3a 0x01>;
  };
};
```

And in my driver probe code:

```
static int bt125_probe(struct i2c_client *client,const struct i2c_device_id *id){
.....
printk(KERN_INFO "%s %sDev: %d\n",MODNAME,__func__,client->dev.id);
.....
}
```

Output is:

```
my_driver bt125_probe Dev: 0
my_driver bt125_probe Dev: 0
```

Comment: Maybe some code will be usefull!

Comment: Hi, check if your i2c devices got into the tree with this command:  `find /sys/devices -iname "*i2c*"`. Also, is your `dmesg` free of i2c errors?